# How to retrieve parent field value

Tags: apex, soql, child-to-parent

Let's say I have this code

```
User tempo = [select contact.name from user where id= :UserInfo.getUserId() limit 1 ][0];
```

how can I take contact.name value from tempo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User tempo = [select contact.name from user where id= :UserInfo.getUserId() limit 1 ];
```

Please use `tempo.contact.Name`